# How to resolve “Blocked by CORS policy” in a mobile app? NOT A WEB APP

Tags: flutter, http, dart, https, http-headers

I am trying to use the sales force api.  But I keep getting a CORS error.  Some try to help by directing me to a solution for a web app that does not work.  For example, one link I was directed to says to add the domain to an "allowed" list.  But I am not coming from a domain, at least not in any way that I know of.  Do all cell phones belong in a domain?  Does each phone have its own domain?  Or is the solution inapplicable.

Another solution I was criticized for duplication said to use "Access-Control-Request-Method" as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe) I was directed to.  But the first problem is that I had to convert everything from web pass to mobile pass.  I have no idea if I did it right.  The second problem is that it still fails with no new information.  A third problem is the link has absolutely no information what value gets assigned to "Access-Control-Request-Method" I tried various guesses but to no avail.

I have ran out of things to guess!

```
void getData() async {

var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer access_token',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://instance-name.salesforce.com/',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, application/json',
};

var res = await http.get(
    'https://instance-name.com/services/data/v20.0/',
    headers: headers);
if (res.statusCode != 200)
  throw Exception('http.get error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}');
print(res.body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party service to avoid CORS policy issue. There are several services available online. You can try https://allorigins.win/ and its works fine. Try following code

```
void getData() async {

var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer access_token',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://instance-name.salesforce.com/',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, application/json',
};

var res = await http.get(
    'https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=https://instance-name.com/services/data/v20.0',
    headers: headers);
if (res.statusCode != 200)
  throw Exception('http.get error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}');
print(res.body);
}
```

Comment: That does not work.  It produces an error "Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Comment: May be you can try after removing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from header.